# React is constantly giving undefined variable error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

Im tryng to repeat react element for certain amount of times.
I have used for loop before and it was working with simple HTML elements.
Now it wont work, constantly getting error that 'fields' array is undefined.
Here is my code:

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import SecondForm from './SecondForm';

function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  [fields, setFields] = useState([]);

  const setFields = () => {
    let numberOfAngles = inputRef.current.value;
    for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfAngles; i++) {
      fields.push(<SecondForm id={i} key={i}></SecondForm>);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>Check is point inide of polygon or not</h1>
      <div className="start-form">
        <p>Select number from 3 to 10 for number of Polygon angles</p>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="nr-of-angles"
          name="nr-ofangles"
          min="3"
          max="10"
          ref={inputRef}
        ></input>
        <button className="btn" onClick={setFields}>
          Sumbit
        </button>
      </div>
      {fields ? fields : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also have tried with .map but still getting same error...
Any help is welcome.

Comment: check for numberOfAngles value that you are using in for loop. Console log it, maybe it is undefined

Comment: Im getting valid "numberOfAngles" but before that I need to coment out half of code...
Here is link to code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-benz-7ipewl?file=/src/App.js so You can Try it.
On sandbox showing is error about 'setFields' and if I change it to simple function Im getting error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `const setFields` overrides the `setFields` from `[fields, setFields] = useState([]);`, and you need to use that to inform react that the array has changed and that it should re-render.

so the fixed code for this approach would be

```js
const inputRef = useRef(null);
const [fields, setFields] = useState([]);

const setFieldsHandler = () => {
  let numberOfAngles = inputRef.current.value;
  const newFields = []
  for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfAngles; i++) {
    newFields.push(<SecondForm id={i} key={i}></SecondForm>);
  }
  setFields(newFields);
};
```

but there really is no reason to hold the whole react components in a state. Just keep the count in the state and use it to render them directly.

```js
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import SecondForm from "./SecondForm";

function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [fieldsCount, setFieldsCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>Check is point inide of polygon or not</h1>
      <div className="start-form">
        <p>Select number from 3 to 10 for number of Polygon angles</p>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="nr-of-angles"
          name="nr-ofangles"
          min="3"
          max="10"
          ref={inputRef}
        ></input>
        <button
          className="btn"
          onClick={(e) => setFieldsCount(inputRef.current.value)}
        >
          Sumbit
        </button>
      </div>
      {Array(fieldsCount)
        .fill()
        .map((_, index) => (
          <SecondForm id={index} key={index}></SecondForm>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, your second solution is much cleaner, it just needed little touch because "fieldsCount" become string and "Array" would have only one component. Here is fix :) 
  ` ` `
    {Array(parseInt(fieldsCount))
        .fill()
        .map((_, index) => (
          <SecondForm id={index} key={index}></SecondForm>
        ))}
` ` `

Comment: Right. It would be better to parse it before setting the state, so it is always in the correct format. So `onClick={(e) => setFieldsCount(parseInt(inputRef.current.value, 10))}` on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Setting directly the fields array is not the right way to change the state using [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook. Instead you should change it using the setFields function.
To add a value to the fields array first spread the previous state, by passing setFields a function, and add the new item to the array.

setFields((prevState) => [...prevState, newItem]);